# need to loop through multiple statements with specific grouping

Tags: php

I have the following php code:

```
$k=1;
for($i=0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM services_main');
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        if ($row['ID'] == $i) {

            for($j=1; $j <= 3; $j++)
            {
                echo $row['name'].' - k='.$k++.' - j='.$j.' | ';
                echo $row['color'].' - k='.$k++.' - j='.$j.'<br />';

            }

        }
    }
}
```

This code generates this:

```
John - k=1 - j=1 | Blue - k=2 - j=1
John - k=3 - j=2 | Blue - k=4 -  j=2
John - k=5 - j=3 | Blue - k=6 -  j=3
Paul - k=7 - j=1 | Green - k=8 -  j=1
Paul - k=9 - j=2 | Green - k=10 -  j=2
Paul - k=11 - j=3 | Green - k=12 -  j=3
George - k=13 - j=1 | Red - k=14 -  j=1
George - k=15 - j=2 | Red - k=16 -  j=2
George - k=17 - j=3 | Red - k=18 -  j=3
```

I would like it to generate this:

```
John - k=1 - j=1 | Blue - k=1 - j=1
John - k=2 - j=2 | Blue - k=2 -  j=2
John - k=3 - j=3 | Blue - k=3 -  j=3
Paul - k=4 - j=1 | Green - k=4 -  j=1
Paul - k=5 - j=2 | Green - k=5 -  j=2
Paul - k=6 - j=3 | Green - k=6 -  j=3
George - k=7 - j=1 | Red - k=8 -  j=1
George - k=8 - j=2 | Red - k=8 -  j=2
George - k=9 - j=3 | Red - k=9 -  j=3
```

Comment: Both of your questions are incredibly basic PHP questions - You should be doing some research on your own or attempting to solve the problem yourself before posting questions about such trivial tasks.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you were only allowed to ask very difficult questions here.  I did try to solve this myself and was having trouble which is why i came here for assistance.

Comment: I never said you need to ask difficult questions. All of your questions have been "I have this, I want it to do this, tell me how", instead of "I am trying to get this, I have tried X, Y, and Z, but they do not work and I am having this specific problem"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is whenever you make "$k++" you increment the $k value, and you are increasing it twice every round in the for loop, try to change to this:

```
for($j=1; $j <= 3; $j++)
{
    echo $row['name'].' - k='.$k.' - j='.$j.' | ';
    echo $row['color'].' - k='.$k.' - j='.$j.'<br />';
    $k++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the `echo` statements have `$k++`, which increments it - basically, you're adding 2 to $k on each run through.

```
echo $row['name'].' - k='.$k.' - j='.$j.' | ';
echo $row['color'].' - k='.$k.' - j='.$j.'<br />';
$k++;
```

Should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($j=1; $j <= 3; $j++)
{
    echo $row['name'].' - k='.$k.' - j='.$j.' | ';
    echo $row['color'].' - k='.$k.' - j='.$j.'<br />';
    $k++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is `ID` not a `WHERE` condition of your `SELECT`?

```
$k = 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM services_main WHERE ID = ' . $i);
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        for ($j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++) {
            echo $row['name'].' - k=' . $k . ' - j=' . $j . ' | ';
            echo $row['color'] . ' - k=' . $k++ . ' - j=' . $j . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```